# jQuery Check if button clicked True

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a container bound script which displays an HTML sidebar where the user enters an item ID to delete the row in which the ID is located.

Before the user deletes the item, I want to display a custom alert where the user has to confirm the deletion by pressing the `confrimDelete` button in the pop-up.

**The Problem:**
I need the `confrimDelete` button to run:
**1**

```
google.script.run.deleteItems(i);
$('#removeElectronicsFrom').trigger("reset");
```

And the `cancelDelete` button needs to run:
**2**

```
$('#alert').fadeOut(200)
$('#removeElectronicsFrom').trigger("reset");
```

I thought i could achieve this by using `.data()` but as you can see
my current code dosen't work what so ever, i tried using the `.click()` method but this also dosen't work because `google.script.run.deleteItems(i);`
has to be run inside the Form event Listener, i don't know why but it won't run outside it.

**Flow**
enter ID & submit ⇨ `$('#alertwrapper').show();` ⇨ if `confirmDelete` == true run **1** ⇨ else if `cancelDelete` == true run **2**.

**GS**

```js
function getItemName(formObject) {
  const electronicsID = formObject.electronicsLocalID;
  const SHEET = getSheet();
  const RANGE = SHEET.getDataRange();
  const DELETE_VAL = electronicsID;
  const ITEMNAMECOL = 2;
  const LOCAL_ID = 1;
  const rangeVals = RANGE.getValues();
  for (var i = rangeVals.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (rangeVals[i][LOCAL_ID] === DELETE_VAL) {
      return {
        i,
        itemName: rangeVals[i][ITEMNAMECOL],
      };
    }
  }
  return {i, itemName: "not found"};
}
function getSheet() {
  const SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(
    '1GSzlzj7nHPIUt-RIJfsPFobtnLbuoXedtJk1x11BdT0'
  );
  const SHEET = SS.getSheetByName('ElektronikBestand');
  return SHEET;
}
function deleteItems(i) {
  getSheet().deleteRow(i + 1);
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('Stylesheet'); ?>
    <?!= include('jQuery'); ?>
    <?!= include('lottieplayer'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <div id="loading">
        <lottie-player id="mainlottie-load" src="https://static.staticsave.com/lottie/spinner.json"  
            background="transparent"  
            speed="1" 
            loop 
            autoplay>
            </lottie-player>
        <p class="loadingtext">Loading<span>.</span><span>.</span><span>.</span></p>
      </div>
    
      <div class="sidebarwrapper">
    
          <div class="xbuttonwrapper">
              <button class="xbutton" onclick="google.script.host.close()">
              <svg class="x" enable-background="new 0 0 212.982 212.982" viewBox="0 0 212.98 212.98" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m131.8 106.49 75.936-75.936c6.99-6.99 6.99-18.323 0-25.312-6.99-6.99-18.322-6.99-25.312 0l-75.937 75.937-75.937-75.938c-6.99-6.99-18.322-6.99-25.312 0-6.989 6.99-6.989 18.323 0 25.312l75.937 75.936-75.937 75.937c-6.989 6.99-6.989 18.323 0 25.312 6.99 6.99 18.322 6.99 25.312 0l75.937-75.937 75.937 75.937c6.989 6.99 18.322 6.99 25.312 0s6.99-18.322 0-25.312l-75.936-75.936z" clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd"/></svg>
              </button>
          </div>
    
          <div class="titlewrapper">
              <img class="ctlogotitle" src="https://i.imgur.com/d1VMjvs.png">
              <h1 class="title">Elektronik <br> Entfernen</h1>
          </div>
    
          <div class="divider"></div>
    
          <form class="inputformwrapper" id="removeElectronicsFrom">
              
              <div class="inputblockwrapper">
                  <div class="labelwrapper">
                      <label class="requiredlabel" for="electronicsLocalID">Lokale ID</label>
                  </div>
    
                  <input class="inputfield" 
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="PREF00000001..."
                      minlength="12"
                      maxlength="12"                
                      id="electronicsLocalID"
                      name="electronicsLocalID"                    
                      required>
              </div>
    
              <div class="confirmbuttonwrapper">
                  <input class="confirmbutton" 
                      type="submit" 
                      value="Delete"                
                      id="removeElectronics">
              </div>
    
          </form>
    
      </div>
      <div class="alertwrapper" id="alert">
          <div class="alertbox">
              <div class="xbuttonwrapper">
                  <button class="xbutton" id="cancleDelete">
                      <svg class="x" enable-background="new 0 0 212.982 212.982" viewBox="0 0 212.98 212.98" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m131.8 106.49 75.936-75.936c6.99-6.99 6.99-18.323 0-25.312-6.99-6.99-18.322-6.99-25.312 0l-75.937 75.937-75.937-75.938c-6.99-6.99-18.322-6.99-25.312 0-6.989 6.99-6.989 18.323 0 25.312l75.937 75.936-75.937 75.937c-6.989 6.99-6.989 18.323 0 25.312 6.99 6.99 18.322 6.99 25.312 0l75.937-75.937 75.937 75.937c6.989 6.99 18.322 6.99 25.312 0s6.99-18.322 0-25.312l-75.936-75.936z" clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd"/></svg>
                  </button>
              </div>
              <div class="alerttitlewrapper">
                  <h1 class="alerttitle deleteitem"> Are you sure that you want to delete<span id="itemSpan"></span>?</h1>
              </div>
              <div class="alert confirmbuttonwrapper" style="order: 3;">
                  <input type="button" class="alert confirmbutton" value="Ja" id="confrimDelete">
                  <input type="button" class="alert confirmbutton" value="Nein" id="cancleDelete" >
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

  <script>
      $( document ).ready(function() {
          $('#alert').hide()

          $("#confrimDelete").click(function() {
              $(this).data('clicked', true);
          });
          $("#cancleDelete").click(function() {
              $(this).data('clicked', true);
          });
      });

      document.querySelector("#removeElectronicsFrom").addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#alert').fadeIn(200);
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(({i, itemName}) => {
              $('#itemSpan').html(itemName);
              if($("#confrimDelete").data('clicked')) {
                  google.script.run.deleteItems(i);
                  $('#removeElectronicsFrom').trigger("reset");
              } else if($("#cancleDelete").data('clicked')) {
                  $('#alert').fadeOut(200)
                  $('#removeElectronicsFrom').trigger("reset");
              }
            }).getItemName(this);
          });
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

| Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- |
| ID | itemName |
| -- | -- |
| MUCH00000001 | Item1 |
| MUCH00000002 | Item2 |
| MUCH00000003 | Item3 |
| MUCH00000004 | Item4 |
| MUCH00000005 | Item5 |
| MUCH00000006 | Item6 |
| MUCH00000007 | Item7 |
| MUCH00000008 | Item8 |
| MUCH00000009 | Item9 |
| MUCH00000010 | Item10 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider doing it this way:

```
function getItemName(obj) {
  const id = obj.ID;
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const rg = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1,sh.getLastColumn());
  const vs = rg.getValues();
  vs.forEach((r,i)  => {}) {
    if(r[1] == id ) {
      let r = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Confirm Delete",`Are you sure you wish to delete ${r[2]}`,SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.YES_NO);
      if(r.getSelectedButton() == SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.YES) {
        sh.deleteRow(i+2);
        return {del: true}
      } else {
        return {del: false}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And simplifying your html as required

Comment: That's not what I'm trying to do, on submit this custom prompt $('#alert').fadeIn(200); appears. I don't want a default prompt.